# FaceBook Integration with Asp.Net website for Recent activity

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can i create a similar functionality like Yahoo has done in www.news.yahoo.com ??
My website has lot of articles. when the user has logged on to FB from my website, the links of the pages he visited in my site should be shown in his FB Recent activity. How ?

[image]

```
Functionality : 

Your Activity : Shows the News that has been read after logged in.

It Posts in Face Book activities.

Social ON : To allow the script to post in FB

Social OFF : To not allow the script to post in FB
```

I tried to create a facebook app and got the AppKey. But it does not give the functionality i need. How can i do this ?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Sample4.aspx.cs" Inherits="Sample4" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div id="Div1"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPKEY";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <div id="Div2"></div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APPKEY";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <div class="fb-activity" data-width="300" data-height="300" data-header="false" data-colorscheme="light" data-linktarget="_blank" data-recommendations="false"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://localhost:27531/FaceBook-Integration/Sample4.aspx" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="tahoma"></div>
  <div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> the links of the pages he visited in my site should be shown in his FB Recent activity. How ?

Familiarize yourself with the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) concept, and read the docs on how to make use of Open Graph actions within your app.

> I tried to create a facebook app and got the AppKey. But it does not give the functionality i need. How can i do this ?

By implementing the features you want your app to have.

Seriously, this question is just to broad to be answered here. Familiarize yourself with the API documentation and the basic concepts, and start from there.